# Distributions of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(\omega, F, P)$ be Lebesgue measeure on$[0,1]$, and set

$X(\omega) = 1$ if $0 \le \omega < \frac{1}{4}$

$X(\omega) = 2\omega^2$ if $\frac{1}{4} \le \omega < \frac{3}{4}$

$X(\omega) = \omega^2$ if $\frac{3}{4} \le \omega \le 1$

Compute $P(X \in A)$ where

(A) $A = [0,\frac{3}{4}]$

(B) $A = [\frac{1}{2},1]$

From a previous question I know that:

(A) $A = [0,1] = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{4}$

(B) $A = [\frac{1}{2},1] = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

However for this problem I need to solve it via one of these equations I'm assuming:
$\mu(B) = P(X \in B) = P(X^{-1}(B)), B \in B$

$\int_\Omega f(X(\omega))P(d\omega) = \int^\infty_{-\infty} f(t)\mu(dt)$

I've been looking around on Google for anything that may be helpful and so far I've found this:
http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/245a-notes-2-the-lebesgue-integral/

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the measure of those values of $\omega$ which give $X(\omega)$ in the required interval

For (A) you need to calculate $\mu\left(\left[0,\frac14\right)\right)+\mu\left(\left[\frac14,\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right) +\mu\left(\left[\frac34,1\right]\right)$

For (B) you need to calculate $\mu\left(\left[0,\frac14\right)\right)+\mu\left(\left[\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right) +\mu\left(\left[\frac34,1\right]\right)$

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you might solve:
$\mu\left(\left[\frac14,\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right)$

I'm having trouble understanding how this is calculated.

Comment: It is just $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac14$ or as you might write it $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Or perhaps you meant "Why is this expression here?"  If $\frac{1}{4} \le \omega \lt \frac{3}{4}$ and $0 \le 2\omega^2 \le 1$ then  $\frac{1}{4} \le \omega \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Perhaps I should have written  $\mu\left(\left[\frac14,\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right]\right)$ with a right square bracket but in this case it makes little difference.